# Custom CursorAdapter to bind to simple_list_item_checked

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor

For example, say I have a SQLite database of todos, each with a string title and an integer completed. How can I create a custom adapter (that extends CursorAdaper) that can bind the checkbox in an `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked` to the integer completed? I already know I have to convert the integer to a boolean, I'm using true = 1 and false = 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please override the bindView abstract Method in your Adapter.

```
 /**
 * Bind an existing view to the data pointed to by cursor
 * @param view Existing view, returned earlier by newView
 * @param context Interface to application's global information
 * @param cursor The cursor from which to get the data. The cursor is already
 * moved to the correct position.
 */
public abstract void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor);
```